# PHP RESTful API to accept authentification

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication

I am working on a PHP REST API.  I would like require a user key to access the API.  I am not sure how to do this though, do I just issue a key and have them send it in a `POST` or with `GET` on each API request?  Please help me explain in the simplest of terms possible if you can, I know this is something a lot of people want to do and it confuses a lot of people not just myself.

Also I would like to be able to limit usage, I was thinking of storing each hit in a MySQL database or something in Memory even.  I just saw this in the header of a Github API request
`X-RateLimi-Limit 5000` and `X-RateLimi-Remaining 4996` and the number decreases by 1 on each hit, is this some kind of built in limiter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing api keys to rest api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567512/passing-api-keys-to-rest-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just require clients to register with your site, 
create a record in your CLIENTS table, issue them a unique, non easy to guess id
then with each api access require that id to be included in request, either in GET or POST on in the header.

Validate it with every request, return error code if id is not present or invalid.

For rate limiting you are correct, you need to have a separate table for storing count of requests per client and then generate these response headers with X-RateLimit counters.

It's not that hard, really.

I wrote an API that does that for my project, you are welcome to look  at the source code, it's in the Api folder, here
https://github.com/snytkine/LampCMS/tree/master/lib/Lampcms/Api/

and entry point to API calls is this
https://github.com/snytkine/LampCMS/blob/master/www/api/api.php

url for adding new app is:
http://support.lampcms.com/index.php?a=editapp

Comment: Thanks, your github code is really helpful for the flow of things

Comment: Just a note, looking through your codebase for LampCMS, probably the best written PHP  project I have seen in 10 years, impressive!

Comment: @CodeDevelopr Thank you. Some day when I have time I really want to rewrite the API using Java Spring 3. They made it so easy to design RESTful Apis and it's probably several times more efficient than even the latest php with APC. I'll make it open source too of cause