# Amazon S3 REST API; how is the API-key transferred firsttime between client and service?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hmac, api-key

Within my research I came across many different sources, but somehow I fail to see, which side is generating the private API-key and how is the other side getting hold of it.

Many people recommend Amazon S3 Restful API as the role model, hence if I understand that, I could create something similar for my own purposes.

[Amazon's S3 REST API.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html)

e.g. this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567512/passing-api-keys-to-rest-api) here explains the process very nicely, however it fails to explain, which side is generating the API-key? So upon user signup, is it the service side that is generating the private API-key and assigns it to the user id in database?

If this is the case though, the client needs to know the API key in order to create the **signature** for each request, so that the service can actually verify it. So how do both sides get hold of the private API key?

In my case I would have a iPhone app and a AngularJS web app as my clients talking to the RESTful API service.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

First, you don't want give out keys to your clients. In general, that's a security nightmare. (Also, key creation can take some hours to propagate. And you'll have to manage the permissions for each key, etc.)  So all the signing is done by your server, and your key doesn't leave your server.

You want your server to have the S3 key, but only return signed links that will give the client the power to do something (GET a particular file, or PUT a file).  It's a bit like the mother-may-I game: The client asks you for a "S3 signed link", then it can talk to S3 to do one thing.  Since your server is doing a trivial amount of work (checking request is authorized, then returning a signed URL), you will be able to scale pretty well.

For some things, like "list files" or "delete a file", it might be better for your server to call S3 (i.e. making a web request to S3 within the web request from the client) and return the results to the client (instead of messing with signed links). But if you do this, you may run into problems when scaling -- unless you are using the right technologies. (I.e. you want an evented server like node.js)

Note that for a PUT request, the signed link must specify a lot of stuff ahead of time (like the file type, etc). You have to read the AWS spec carefully.

Be careful of the [Confused Deputy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_Deputy) problem. Your code will have one key that can see all user's files, so you are responsible for the security between users.